# R boxplot frequency

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm in need of assistance... I'm using **R** to analyze some data... I have a frequency table called mytable... that I created like this:

```
mytable=table(cut(var1,12),cut(var2,12))
```

the table looks something like this:

```
       1-2  2-3  3-4
1-3     2    1    2
3-6     0    1    4
6-9     7    1    8
```

except is a 12 by 12 table.

I used `boxplot.matrix(mytable)`,the boxplot looks ok... with the 12 boxes corresponding to my 12 stratums, but my boxplot has the frequency as the y-axis and I want the y-axis to be the values from var1, how can I do this?

I wanted to post a pic... but my rep wasnt high enough

Comment: A boxplot generally plots a distribution rather than a summary of data.  Instead, try something like `boxplot(var1, subset=cut(var2, 12))`.  That way, the function is doing the summarization work for you

Comment: this only shows 1 box... and i need all 12.. =(

Comment: Take a read of `?boxplot`.  Sometimes, I like to give partial answers and let you do a little research and learning on your own when it seems like the answer is apparent.  `boxplot(var1 ~ cut(var2, 12))

Comment: jesus.... i had the answer... but for some reason R was doing it wrong... restart pc fixed it..ty man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `boxplot` before you summarize your data.

```
boxplot(var1)
```

If you want to see the distribution per split, use the formula format:

```
boxplot(var1 ~ cut(var2, 12))
```